# How do I add text labels to the X-axis of an scatter plot in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to use a scatter plot to represent data pertaining to five regions. How can I customise the x-axis to display text labels in stead of numerical values?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have a column for the x-axis text next to the columns for the values with row headers at the top for each region, you should be able to select all the data and the automatic chart tool should pick it up. OR does something go wrong, in which case provide a screenshot

Comment: The requirements in the question aren't clear.  For example, do the regions fall in distinct ranges on X?  Is what is desired really a series of XY charts, one for each region, stacked next to each other?  Is XY the wrong type of chart for what the OP wants?  This can't be answered without clarification, and the OP hasn't returned since asking the question 3 yrs ago.

Answer (score 0):

A scatter plot by definition is plotting with 2 coordinate points (x,y) so it makes sense that the numbers are displayed on both the y axis and x axis.

Is there a reason you want to use a scatter chart instead of a line chart (hide the line so it's just points) and you can label the axis with whatever text you want.

If you actually need a scatter plot you have two options.

- Use conditional formatting if the text request is simple (example is add the same text in front of each number)
- Create a dummy series at y=0 (or whatever your grid minimum is).  Use a tool like [xy chart labeller](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) to label the points and then make the dummy points "no colour"  You are left with the text labels at the bottom of the chart and they will likely overlap the actual x-axis so hide the axis

Answer (score 0):

Don't select whole columns/rows.  Only select a range.
THEN the first column becomes the "data range" for the x-axis (with appropriate formatting, datatype, ...)

This also spreads your data out based on the values in the first column.  Useful if your first column is not evenly spaced values.

It is NOT "labels" per se, but a range based on your data instead of just "data point numbers"

You can discuss with your deities if it is a true scatter plot, BUT, for some folks, it is a useful presentation of data that Excel (spreadsheets) support.